# System.JSONException in Lightning: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In the below code,method2 is calling twice.In the first call itsnt throwing any error but in second time call.It caues below error

Error: *System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set*

```
 List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > 
   )System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);
```

---

```
<aura:component controller="ActionController"  implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="theId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="wrplst" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="deleteJob" event="c:deleteJobEvt" action="{!c.RemoveClick}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <p>
        <center><h5><b>Creating Action Criteria </b></h5></center>
    </p>
    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">
        <b>
            <I> Action Criteria</I>
        </b>
    </h3>
    <table >
        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
            <th class="head">
                <I>Action</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Object Name</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Component</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Operator</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator * Value</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator / Value</I>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.wrplst.length > 0}">
            <p>wrapper Length:{!v.wrplst.length}</p>
           <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
                <c:NewAction wrp="{!a}" options="{!v.options}" selectedValue=""  idval="{!v.theId}"/>
             </aura:iteration>
        </aura:renderIf>
    </table>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add row" onclick="{!c.AddRow}" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand"  label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveRow}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

```
    ({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.pageLoad(component);
        helper.componentVal(component);

    },
    doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.Method2(component);
    },
    RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selCont = event.getParam("selectedJob");
        var conts = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var contsval = JSON.stringify(conts);

        var Selndex = conts.indexOf(selCont);

        var DeleteLen = conts.length;
        //alert('deleteLen value::::' + DeleteLen);
        var removeAction=component.get("c.removeRow");
        removeAction.setParams({
            "wrvalue":contsval,
            "rowval":Selndex 
        });
        removeAction.setCallback(this, function(g) {
            var state = g.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                alert('success value');
                component.set("v.wrplst",JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
            }
            else if(state==='error'){
                alert('error value');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(removeAction);
    },
    AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {

        var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);
        var mapRecords = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < comp1.length; i++) {
            mapRecords.push(comp1[i]);
        }
        var len = mapRecords.length;

        var newlen = len + 1;

        var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
        addAction.setParams({
            "wrapval": compJson1,
            "counterval": newlen,
        });
        addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
            var state = res.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue()));
            } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
                alert('error');
            } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
                alert('incompltete');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
    },
    saveRow: function(component, event, helper) {
        var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
        alert('Id value ::::' + Idx);
        var com = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var comJson = JSON.stringify(com);

        var saveAction = component.get("c.saveCall");
        saveAction.setParams({
            "wrvalue": comJson,
            "id": Idx,
        });
        saveAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
    }
});
```

---

```
    ({
    pageLoad: function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.pageLoading");
        var self = this;
        var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
        action.setParams({
            "id": Idx
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(g) {
            var state = g.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {

                component.set("v.wrplst",JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
                self.Method2(component);

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },

    Method2: function(component, event, helper) {

        var comp = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
        var Id1 = component.get("v.theId");
        var compAction = component.get("c.getComponent");  //First time method call its working fine
        compAction.setParams({
            "wrapval":compJson,
            "id": Id1,
        });
        compAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state ==='SUCCESS') {
               var da=re.getReturnValue();
               var myJSON = re.getReturnValue();
               var myObj = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
                alert('myJson value:::::'+myObj);
               }
            else if(state==='error'){
                alert('error value');
            }
                else if(state==='INCOMPLETE'){
                    alert('incomplete values:::');

                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(compAction);
    },
    componentVal:function(component,event,helper){

        var action=component.get("c.ObjectNames");
        action.setCallback(this,function(re){
            var state=re.getState();
            if(state==='SUCCESS'){

                component.set("v.options",JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue()));
            }
            else if(state==='Error'){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

---

second component:

```
<aura:attribute required="true" name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="wpchange" type="List" />
<aura:registerEvent name="deleteJob" type="c:deleteJobEvt"/>

<tr>
    <td class="cell" style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
        <p >
            <button type="button" onclick="{!c.RemoveClick}" >remove</button>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
          <lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme}" aura:id="obc" onchange="{!c.dosomething}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select> 
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell" >

        <p>
            <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.Operator}">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c',
                             v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c', 
                              v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Section_Master__c')}">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                    </aura:if>
               </lightning:select>
        </p>

    </td>

    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
            <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.Operator}">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="+ Addition">+ Addition</option>
                <option value="- Subtract  ">- Subtract</option>
                <option value="* Multiply ">* Multiply</option>
                <option value="/ Divide">/ Divide</option>
            </lightning:select>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
            <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.SpecialOperator}">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="*">*</option>
                <option value="*/">*/</option>
                <option value="/">/</option>
            </lightning:select>
        </p>
    </td>

    <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
        <p>
            <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorValue}"/>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
        <p>
            <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorSlashValue}"/>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
({
    RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {

        var event1 = component.getEvent("deleteJob");

        event1.setParams({
            'selectedJob': component.get("v.wrp"),
        });
        event1.fire();
    },
    dosomething:function(component, event, helper) {
        var x=component.find("obc").get("v.value");
        alert('x value::::'+x);
        var comp = component.get("v.wrp");
        var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
        alert('compJson val ::::'+compJson);
        var Id1 = component.get("v.idval");
        alert('Id1 val::::::'+Id1);

        var Action = component.get("c.getComponent");  //second time call shows error in server side
        Action.setParams({
            "wrapval": compJson,
            "id": Id1,
        });
        Action.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state ==='SUCCESS') {
                alert('sucess value :::');
               //Here Ive to set components value
               //components1 values as well
            }
            else if(state==='error'){
                alert('error value');
            }
                else if(state==='INCOMPLETE'){
                    alert('incomplete values:::');

                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(Action); 
    }
  })
```

---

server:

```
    public class ActionController
     {
@AuraEnabled
public static string pageLoading(string id) {

    List < Action_Criteria__c > RecordsInserted = new List < Action_Criteria__c > ();
    List < WrapperCriteria > wList = new List < WrapperCriteria > ();
    Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();
    cmas=[select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id =:id];
    RecordsInserted = [select id, Action_Criteria_API_Name__c, Action_Criteria_Field_Name__c, Criteria_Master__c, Object_API_Name__c, Operator__c, Object_Name__c, Special_Operator__c, Special_operator_slash_value__c, Special_operator_value__c from Action_Criteria__c where Criteria_Master__c = : id order by Sequence_No__c];
    system.debug('record Inserted values:::' + RecordsInserted);
    Integer counter=1;
    for (Action_Criteria__c ac: RecordsInserted) {
        WrapperCriteria wrp = new WrapperCriteria();
        wrp.record = ac;
        wrp.ObjectApiNAme = ac.Object_API_Name__c;
        wrp.FieldName = ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c;
        wrp.index =counter;
        counter=counter+1;
        wrp.CriteriaMasId = ac.Criteria_Master__c;
        wrp.Operator = ac.Operator__c;
        wrp.SpecialOperator = ac.Special_Operator__c;
        wrp.specialOperatorSlashValue = ac.Special_operator_slash_value__c;
        wrp.specialOperatorValue = ac.Special_operator_value__c;
        wList.add(wrp);
    }

    return JSON.serialize(wList);
}
@AuraEnabled
public static string ObjectNames()
{

    List<SelectOption> ObjNames= new List<SelectOption>();
    ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c','Pay Element'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c','CTC Master'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Section_Master__c','Section Master'));
    return JSON.serialize(ObjNames);
}

@AuraEnabled
public static string getComponent(string wrapval,string id) {
    String objectName;
    Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();
    system.debug('iam calling');
    system.debug('id val:::::::'+id);

    //List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > )System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);
    List < WrapperCriteria > warpList;
    try {
        warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > )System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria>.class); 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        WrapperCriteria warp = (WrapperCriteria)System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, WrapperCriteria.class);
        warpList.add(warp);
     }
    system.debug('::::::wrList value::::' + warpList);
    system.debug('id value ::::::' + id);

     WrapperCriteria dc=new WrapperCriteria ();

    WrapperCriteria ac=new WrapperCriteria ();
    List < SelectOption > ObjNames = new List < SelectOption > ();
    ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c', 'Pay Element'));
    ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c', 'CTC Master'));

    Map <String,String> ctcMasAPINames = new Map < String, String > ();
    cmas = [select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:id];

    if (warpList.size() > 0) {
        for (WrapperCriteria wr: warpList) {
            List <SelectOption > options = new List <SelectOption > ();
            if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'Pay_Element_Master__c') {
                for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                    if (so.Value == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                        objectName = so.Label;
                        system.debug('****objectname *****' + objectName);
                    }
                }
                system.debug('wr.SelObjectName value ::::::'+ wr.SelObjectName);
                system.debug('object name:::::::::::::'+objectName);
                try{
                    if(wr.SelObjectName==null){
                       wr.SelObjectName = objectName;                          
                }
                }catch (exception e){
                    system.debug('e value'+e);
                }




                for (Pay_Element_Master__c pem: [select id, name, Company_Master__c from Pay_Element_Master__c where Company_Master__c = : cmas.Company_Master__c]) {
                    options.add(new SelectOption(pem.id, pem.name));
                    //dc.componentMap.put(pem.id,pem.name);
                    ctcMasAPINames.put(pem.id, pem.name);
                    System.debug('--------Pay element MAster MAP VAlues-----' + ctcMasAPINames);
                }
                ac.Components = options;
                system.debug('ac.Components value:::::::'+ac.Components);
            } 
            else if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'CTC_Master__c') {
                for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                    if (so.Value == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                        objectName = so.Label;
                        system.debug('-----------objectname --------------' + objectName);
                    }
                }
                wr.SelObjectName = objectName;
                Map < String, Schema.SObjectType > globalDescription = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
                Schema.sObjectType objType = globalDescription.get('CTC_Master__c');
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ob = objType.getDescribe();

                if (ob == Null) {
                    AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('Invalid sObject Type');
                    e.setMessage('Invalid sObject Type');
                    system.debug(e);
                    throw e;

                }
                Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > mapFieldList = ob.fields.getMap();

                for (Schema.SObjectField field: mapFieldList.values()) {
                    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
                    if (fieldResult.isAccessible() && (fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Integer || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Double || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Currency)) {
                        options.add(new SelectOption(fieldResult.getName(), fieldResult.getLabel()));
                        //dc.componentMap1.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());
                        ctcMasAPINames.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());   
                    }
                }
                ac.Components1= options;
                system.debug('ac.Components1 value:::::::'+ac.Components1);
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug('ac ::::::value :::::'+ac);
    return JSON.serialize(ac);

}


@AuraEnabled
public static string addRow(string wrapval,integer counterval ){
    system.debug('counter value::::'+counterval);
    List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List<WrapperCriteria >)JSON.deserialize(wrapval,List<WrapperCriteria >.class);

    WrapperCriteria objInnerClass = new WrapperCriteria();
    Action_Criteria__c newAc= new Action_Criteria__c();        
    objInnerClass.record = newAc;
    objInnerClass.index = counterval;
    warpList.add(objInnerClass);    
    system.debug('------warpList---->'+warpList); 
    return JSON.serialize(warpList);
}
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveCall(string wrvalue,string id){
    List<Action_Criteria__c> RecordsToBeInserted=new List<Action_Criteria__c>();
    Map <String,String> ctcMasAPINames = new Map < String, String > ();
    system.debug('save functionality is calling::::');
    List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria >) JSON.deserialize(wrvalue, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);
    system.debug('::::::::::::warpList::::::::::::::::'+warpList);
    system.debug('id value:::::::::::'+id);
    List<Criteria_Master__c> updatedCrimasters=new List<Criteria_Master__c>();
    Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();

    cmas=[select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id =:id];
    ID cid=cmas.id;
    system.debug('cid value ::::::'+cid);

    if(warpList!=null && !warpList.isEmpty())
    {
        for(WrapperCriteria wf: warpList)
        {
            system.debug('wrapper calling::::::::::::::::::::');
           // if(!string.isBlank(wf.SelObjectName) && !string.isBlank(wf.FieldName))
            //{    
                Action_Criteria__c ac= wf.record;
                ac.Criteria_Master__c =cid ;
                ac.Object_Name__c=wf.SelObjectName;
                if(wf.Operator!='None')
                {
                    ac.Operator__c=wf.Operator;
                }
                ac.Object_API_Name__c=wf.ObjectApiNAme;
                ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c=wf.FieldName;
                ac.Special_operator_slash_value__c = wf.specialOperatorSlashValue;
                ac.Special_operator_value__c = wf.specialOperatorValue;
                // System.debug('-----fc.object api--------'+ctcMasAPINames.ContainsKey(wf.FieldName));
                if(ctcMasAPINames.ContainsKey(wf.FieldName)) 
                {
                    if(ac.Object_API_Name__c=='Pay_Element_Master__c')
                    {
                        ac.Action_Criteria_Field_Name__c= ctcMasAPINames.get(wf.FieldName);
                    }
                    if(ac.Object_API_Name__c=='CTC_Master__c')
                    {
                        ac.Action_Criteria_Field_Name__c= ctcMasAPINames.get(wf.FieldName);
                        System.debug('-------------'+ctcMasAPINames.get(wf.FieldName));
                    }

                }
                system.debug('==fc==>'+ac);
                RecordsToBeInserted.add(ac);

            //}
        }

        system.debug('==RecordsToBeInserted==>'+RecordsToBeInserted.size());
        upsert RecordsToBeInserted;
        for(Criteria_Master__c cm:[select id,Name,Filter_Criteria__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:id])
        {
            string ActionCriteria;
            if(!RecordsToBeInserted.isEmpty())
            {
                for(Action_Criteria__c ac: [select id, Object_API_Name__c,Action_Criteria_API_Name__c, Sequence_No__c, Operator__c, Criteria_Master__c from Action_Criteria__c where Criteria_Master__c=:id order by  Sequence_No__c asc])
                {
                    if(string.isBlank(ActionCriteria))
                    {
                        ActionCriteria =  string.valueof(ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ActionCriteria =  ActionCriteria + string.valueof(ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c);
                    }
                    if(ac.Operator__c=='+ Addition')
                    {
                        ActionCriteria = ActionCriteria +'+';    
                    }
                }
                if(!string.isBlank(ActionCriteria))
                {
                    cm.Action_Criteria_Logic__c =  ActionCriteria;
                }
                cm.Action_Criteria__c =True;
                updatedCrimasters.add(cm);
            }
        }
        update updatedCrimasters;
        system.debug('update criteria master::::::::::'+updatedCrimasters);
    }
}
@AuraEnabled
public static string removeRow(string wrvalue,integer rowval){
    system.debug('::::: rowToRemove val  :::::'+rowval);

    List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > ) JSON.deserialize(wrvalue, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);
    system.debug('::::::wrList value::::' + warpList);
    rowval = Integer.valueOf(rowval);
    if(!string.isBlank(string.valueof(rowval)))
    {
        Action_Criteria__c acdelete = warpList[rowval].record;
        list<Action_Criteria__c> listAc = new list<Action_Criteria__c>();

        if(!string.isblank(acdelete.id))
        {
            Criteria_Master__c criteriaMaster = [select id,Name,Action_Criteria__c,(select id, Criteria_Master__c from Action_Criteria__r where id!=:acdelete.id ) from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:acdelete.Criteria_Master__c];
            listAc = [select id, Criteria_Master__c from Action_Criteria__c where id!=:acdelete.id and Criteria_Master__c=:acdelete.Criteria_Master__c];
            if(criteriaMaster.Action_Criteria__r.isEmpty())
            {
                criteriaMaster.Action_Criteria__c = false;
                update criteriaMaster;
            }
            delete acdelete;
        }
    }
    warpList.remove(rowval);
    system.debug('wraper List  *******'+warpList);
    return JSON.serialize(warpList);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Annappa in your code for the first time you are passing list of your wrapperclass and you deserialize as a list that is correct. but for the seconde time you passing sing wrapperclass object you are trying to deserialize to a list so i think beacuse of that you getting error. so try the below code.

```
       List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = new List < WrapperCriteria >();
       try {
            warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > )System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria>.class); 
       } catch(Exception e) {
            WrapperCriteria warp = (WrapperCriteria)System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, WrapperCriteria.class);
            warpList.add(warp)
       }
```

And i believe you defined wrp attribute in your component type as WrapperCriteria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56409/discussion-between-blackperl-saf-and-annappa-ph).